# how to find latest instance between two columns and get the a value from a different column for that instance?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

I have a match history dataset and I want to find the latest up to date elo for the players. I'm working with python & pandas and a sample of the dataset is this:

```
  tournament_date    winner_id   loser_id    winner_elo    loser_elo   winner_delta   loser_delta     other_columns  
 ----------------- ------------ ---------- ------------- ------------ -------------- --------------- --------------- 
  2017-08-24               512        543          1128         1102              6              -6             ...  
  2017-08-24               100        517          1153         1062            0.4            -0.4             ...  
  2017-08-24               512        547          1128         1114            3.4            -3.4             ...  
  2017-08-24               543        517          1102         1062            4.8            -4.8             ...  
  2017-08-24               547        100          1114         1153           11.2           -11.2             ...  
  2017-08-24               517        512          1062         1128            9.9            -9.9             ...  
  2017-08-24               543        100          1102         1153            9.1            -9.1             ...  
  2017-08-24               517        547          1062         1114            9.1            -9.1             ...  
  2017-08-26               543        517          1103         1089            5.2            -5.2             ...  
  2017-08-26               547        551          1119         1165            8.8            -8.8             ...  
  2017-08-26               543        557          1103         1214            8.5            -8.5             ...  
  2017-08-26               551        517          1165         1089              1              -1             ...  
  2017-08-26               557        547          1089         1119            7.8            -7.8             ...  
  2017-08-26               551        543          1165         1103              3              -3             ...
```

winner_elo and loser_elo are updated daily in my dataset but for every match there is a column for the delta change for winners and losers.

I want to find the latest entry for each player_id (either in winner_id or loser_id) and if it's in the winner_id column to do winner_elo + winner_delta to find the up to date elo or if the latest instance of a player is in the loser_id column to calculate loser_elo + loser_delta.

There are around 1000 unique player id's (500 unique winner_id's and 508 loser_id's). I tried grouping by winner_id, sorting by date and getting the max and similarly grouping by loser_id and sorting by date but I don't know how to compare them and find out which one is the latest and then do the calculation that it's required.

I can only think of solutions that involve for loops and if's but I guess there must be a better way

Edit: this is part of a web scraping project and I'm getting new data daily so I would prefer a solution that's suitable for newer entries

Comment: The added updates make this a different problem from a design perspective, somewhat more broad than Stack Overflow handles.

Answer (score 0):

I would attack this by splitting the data frame in two: drop the loser data from one, the winner data from the other, and rename the columns as simply "id". "elo" and "delta".  Simply concatenate the two frames, sort by date (most recent first), and `groupby` player ID.

Now, for each player, simply skim off the top (most recent) row and apply it to get the current rating.

Comment: Just edited the original post, that I get new data daily so I'm not sure if this solution is optimal